# Понятие комнаты

Tags: лексика

Есть такие понятия, как "однокомнатная квартира", "двухкомнатная квартира" и т. д. Означает ли это, что называть комнатой кухню, кладовую, гостиную, коридор некорректно и писать о том, что человек "ушёл в другую комнату", когда он направился в кухню, не следует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фраза «ушёл в другую комнату» корректна по отношению к комнатам: детской комнате, кладовой комнате, гардеробной комнате, ванной (душевой) комнате, столовой комнате, и пр. Современная кухня, если это не только «горячий цех», а *кухня-столовая*, может входить в этот список.

Второе, и не связанное с вопросом: понятие *квартира* подразумевает наличие жилой площади (комнат) и нежилой, подсобной. Эти последние (помещения) имеют площадь, часто более значительную, чем жилая, но именно справка о количестве жилых комнат (теперь во многом формально) является основной характеристикой жилья, всегда идущей первой строкой.